# How to use dynamic image path in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new in reactjs and i am working with nextjs,I am fetching image from datbase via api, Right now i am getting image name with full path ( url.com/imagename) but i want to know how can we use dynamic path, in other words if i have only "image name" (not full path) so how can i append "image path" for display image using next js? I tried with following code

```
{this.state.books.map((post, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="col-md-4"
              <div className="bookimg">
                <img src={post.image} />
              </div>
            </div>
         )
    })}
```

Comment: Is these images exist inside your project?

Comment: _"if i have only "image name" (not full path) so how can i append "image path" for display image"_ - Isn't this just a matter of appending the dynamic path to the image domain, e.g. ``const imageSrc = `https://example.com/${post.image}`;``?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that post.image give you the image name only with mimi type.

```
{this.state.books.map((post, index) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4"
          <div className="bookimg">
            <img src={`myurl.com/image/${post.image}`} />
          </div>
        </div>
     )
})}
```

Comment: actually i am trying to fetch image ( inserted by admin panel which is created in php not in react) so url will be "myurl.com/image/imagename" so right now i have image name ( fetching from db via api) so i am asking how can i append "imagepath" in front of that image, Hope you understand my point

Comment: So it will be src={`myurl.com/image/${post.image}`}, I updated the answer, please check.